# How do I increase available sockets using Mina on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, ubuntu, mina

How do I increase the number of sockets that may be opened on ubuntu when using Mina 2.0.8? Once my server reaches around ~1700 connections, I get this in my logs:

`2013-01-24 04:21:49,465 [NioSocketAcceptor-1] WARN  o.a.m.util.DefaultExceptionMonitor - Unexpected exception.
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:163) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.accept(NioSocketAcceptor.java:159) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.accept(NioSocketAcceptor.java:50) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.processHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:506) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:447) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [na:1.6.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) [na:1.6.0_20]`

How is this possible when my file handles are set to a max of 331278 for hard and soft?
Running "ulimit -n" reports

```
331287
```

and running "sysctl fs.file-nr" reports

```
fs.file-nr = 1728   0   331287
```

Contents of /etc/security/limits.conf file

```
* hard nofile 331287
* soft nofile 331287
```

Comment: Are you sure the limits are set properly for the user running the web app?  ulimits are set on a per-user basis.

Comment: Did you try to set the limits into `limits.conf`? Maybe what you see with `ulimit -n` is valid only for the current shell user but not for the user running Mina daemon

Comment: I added the limits content above; the daemon starts via init.d using sudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things seem to have fixed the issue I was having above:

1. Increasing the file handles for the "root" user specifically since its not included when using "*" in limits.conf.
2. Editing my init.d script to include force setting the ulimit for the process being created. There is apparently a known issue in Ubuntu dealing with process daemon file handles. This link has the details: http://www.jayway.com/2012/02/11/how-to-really-fix-the-too-many-open-files-problem-for-tomcat-in-ubuntu/